# htaccess filter doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i'm trying to rewrite my url's, but i'm also using a router.
so i want the router to control error pages such as error 404 not found, and not my htaccess file. everything is working perfectly fine, except for the filter string in my htaccess file. this is the rewrite line:

```
    RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-\_]+)$    index.php?urlpath=$1
```

so then issue is that it doesn't accept characters like . and /

so this works: https://www.mystem.tk/aurlthatdoesntexist

but this won't work: https://www.mystem.tk/apagethatdoesntexist.php

and this won't work either: http://www.mystem.tk/a/url/that/doesnt/exist

last one: https://www.mystem.tk/a/page/that/doesnt/exist.php

i hope my problem is clear on this way...  you can check it out yourself at https://www.mystem.tk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to your regex `[a-zA-Z0-9-z\-\_]+` which doesn't allow dot or forward slashes.

You can use this rule instead of your existing rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ index.php?urlpath=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: it thinks the url is "urlpath=" and not "urlpath=about"

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. I fixed a typo in my rule, please try it now

Comment: thanks man, that fixed it! ive set youre question to be the fix for this issue!

Comment: btw, since im still developing my website, i was wondering if you like my website?

Comment: I liked it very much. Sleek & stylish look

Comment: thnx, i appreciate that very much!